# Number of $k$-cycles in a random Mallows permutation

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, permutations

It is well-known that for uniform random permutations, the number of $k$ cycles for fixed $k$ is distributed as a Poisson random variable with mean $1/k$.

I am looking for similar results on the random $q$ Mallows permutations. In this model we have
$$ \mathbb{P}  [ \{\pi \}  ]  = \frac{q^{\operatorname{inv(\pi)}}}{Z_{n,q}}, $$
where $\operatorname{inv}(\pi)$ counts the number of pairs $i<j$ s.t. $\pi_i > \pi_j$ (the number of inversions) and $Z_{n,q}$ is a normalization constant. I am interested in particular in fixed $q\neq 1$. If $q=1$ we in fact recover the uniform random distribution on permutations.

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.06991) Gladkich and Peled show among other things that $$\mathbb{E} [\text{number of cycles}] \approx (1-q)n + \log (n+1)$$ for $0<q<1$ (Thm 1.5). But I cannot find anything on the (expected) number of, say, $3$-cycles.

Does anyone know of any good references into this? I've spent quite some time looking but its been hard to find any. Thanks in advance!

Comment: From the abstract of the paper you linked to: "In the second regime, we prove that the distribution of normalized cycle lengths follows the Poisson-Dirichlet law, as in a uniformly random permutation." Isn't this directly what you're inquiring about? (Of course, this is only when $(1-q)^{-2}$ is asymptotically greater than $n$, and you might care about all regimes of $q$.)

Comment: @SamHopkins Thanks for the response. I am looking at fixed $q$ and the "second regime" they describe is when $(1-q)^{-2} \gg n$, which necessarily requires that $q=q(n) \to 1$.

Comment: Gotcha (I missed the "fixed $q$" on first read, sorry). Still might be relevant information for those looking at your question, though.

Comment: Indeed, the paper is very insightful and interesting. It just seems a bit strange to me that it is (seemingly) so hard to find any reference about such a basic statistic as the number of fixed points. Perhaps it is actually quite hard.

Comment: I think it is hard. Cycles in permutations have a natural "exponential" structure to them, which allows one to prove in a very elementary way the Poisson distribution result in the uniform case. But inversions do not play nicely at all with this exponential structure of cycles.

Comment: You might look at Edelman's paper https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82751622.pdf, which discusses the joint distribution of cycles and inversions in permutations.

Comment: @IraGessel Thanks that looks interesting!

Comment: This new preprint on the arXiv addresses this question (but perhaps OP=Jimmy He?): https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.09789

Comment: Another new preprint addressing this question: https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.11610